# copying and pasting specific values of a row

Tags: vba, excel

This might be too easy for you but i am new at vba. I have the following code; which opens multiple files as my masterfile is open.

```
  Dim StrFile As String
 Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim InputFilePath As String
 InputFilePath = "Z:\1000_Entwicklung\05_PROJECT\0558000_CFT    \055800L_CFT_Projektleitung\99_Arbeitsordner PL\Tanverdi, Yigit\SAA\"
 StrFile = Dir(InputFilePath & "*")

Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(InputFilePath & StrFile)
    WB.Activate
        sheets("data").Select
        sheets("data").Move After:=Workbooks("makrotochange.xlsm").sheets(23)
        StrFile = Dir()
Loop

   Dim copiedSheet As Worksheet
   Dim masterSheet As Worksheet

Set copiedSheet = Worksheets("data")
Set masterSheet= Worksheets("masterSheet")
```

I want to copy the cells Columns A; B; C; D from every row in data sheet then paste it to mastersheets first empty row, to the Column D; C; A; B in order (cell A will be pasted to cell D in masterSheet, B to C, C to C and D to B etc).

The row amount is dynamic, so i want to be able to copy A;B;C;D of any row that copiedSheet includes and paste this to the first empty row in the masterSheets D;C;A;B cells.

Does anyone know how i can do this?

EDIT:
i want to have a copiedSheet2 which should operate the same thing, but it should paste the destination (masterSheet) in to next empty row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're after. It's the cleanest way to copy data from one location to another without using `.Select` anywhere

```
copiedSheet.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:= masterSheet.Range("D:D")
copiedSheet.Range("B:B").Copy Destination:= masterSheet.Range("C:C")
copiedSheet.Range("C:C").Copy Destination:= masterSheet.Range("A:A")
copiedSheet.Range("D:D").Copy Destination:= masterSheet.Range("B:B")
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! i have one more qeustion, what if i want to have a copiedSheet2 which should operate the same thing, but it should paste the destination (masterSheet) in to next empty row?

Comment: @BartuSaner If the answer is correct then please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as such and (possibly) up-vote the answer. If you have a new question then you should post a new question. You can (of course) link to this post in your new question if you believe such a reference to be of value. BTW: *(+1)* from my side for this post.